# How to output the hostnames of app services created with for_each in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have the following terraform module:

```
provider "azurerm" {
}

variable "env" {
    type = string
    description = "The SDLC environment (qa, dev, prod, etc...)"
}

variable "appsvc_names" {
    type = list(string)
    description = "The names of the app services to create under the same app service plan"
}

locals {
    location = "eastus2"
    resource_group_name = "app505-dfpg-${var.env}-web-${local.location}"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "asp" {
    name                = "${local.resource_group_name}-asp"
    location            = local.location
    resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
    kind                = "Linux"
    reserved            = true

    sku {
        tier = "Basic"
        size = "B1"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "appsvc" {
    for_each            = toset(var.appsvc_names)

    name                = "${local.resource_group_name}-${each.value}-appsvc"
    location            = local.location
    resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
    app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.asp.id
}

# output "hostnames" {
#     value       = azurerm_app_service.appsvc[*].default_site_hostname
#     description = "The hostnames of the created app services"
# }
```

It works, but I want to output the hostnames. Preferrably as a map, but for now just a list could be fine too.

When I uncomment the output statement and run `terraform apply` I get this:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ..\..\modules\web\main.tf line 42, in output "hostnames":
  42:     value       = azurerm_app_service.appsvc[*].default_site_hostname

This object does not have an attribute named "default_site_hostname".
```

So how do I output the list (or better the map) of hostnames of the new app services?

(The question is also posted here - https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-output-the-hostnames-of-app-services-created-with-for-each-in-terraform/5405)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
output "instance_private_ip_addresses" {
  # Result is a map from instance id to private IP address, such as:
  #  {"i-1234" = "192.168.1.2", "i-5678" = "192.168.1.5"}
  value = {
    for instance in aws_instance.example:
    instance.id => instance.private_ip
  }
}
```